# GetListitems results from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

The GetListitems web service relies on XML to retrieve data from SharePoint.

Some actual working code is:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<Document><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"DeliveryStatus\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Created</Value></Contains></Where></Query><ViewFields /><QueryOptions /></Document>");
            XmlNode listQuery = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Query");
            XmlNode listViewFields = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ViewFields");
            XmlNode listQueryOptions = doc.SelectSingleNode("//QueryOptions");
            XmlNode items = wsLists.GetListItems(ListName, string.Empty, listQuery, listViewFields, string.Empty, listQueryOptions, null);
```

Once XMLNode is populated, is there a tried and tested way to traverse the collection of childnodes?

I know how to do this using .net general techniques, but what concerns me is that there might be some pitfalls I am unaware of. For example, I noticed the firstChild and lastChild are empty during some of my tests. I wonder if this is an exception rather than a rule. Its impossible to know from MSDN documentation, so if any of you guys have experience with this please share.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean FirstChild and LastChild sometimes are empty? Well, if you have tags like `<QueryOptions />` and such, then it means they have no childs. By logic I guess that those properties must be empty then.

Or is there any other problem than that?